# Связь кода с доменом/сервером

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api

появилась потребность в совместной работе двух ботов в телеграмм( один присылает данные, второй обрабатывает, второй даже не совсем ТГ бот а именно обработчик, почему решили именно так не спрашивайте:) ), вычитал одну статью что можно реализовать это так что один бот отправляет запрос к моему домену который я регнул, допустим в виде:

domain.com/send.php?api_key=тут_ключ&тут_данные&тут_данные

кроме этого никаких пояснений дано не было

далее мне нужно вытащить эти данные как я понимаю get запросом чтобы обработать их. Вопрос первый как это реализовывается в коде, вопрос второй что за апи ключ на домене.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что у вас запущено серверное приложение на домене domain.com. Оно умеет обрабатывать запросы по http. api_key - это секретный ключ, который вы как разработчик этого серверного приложения сгенерировали и серверное приложение его знает (он где-то записан в конфигурации приложения). Если клиент прислал этот ключ, то приложение знает, что клиент имеет право делать этот запрос. Речь тут идет о том, что можно написать такое приложение.

Comment: А не подскажите какие нибудь ресурсы/статьи где говорится об этом или гайд какой чтобы это реализовать? потребность в этом есть потому что

Comment: Технологии для создания веб-приложения выбирайте по своему вкусу/опыту. Их есть [много](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks): django, flask, aiohttp, fastapi - довольно популярные.